# Remove words with colon from column - why does it not work?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

This is my pandas data frame

```
Description                        ID       Date
wa119:d Here comes the first row   id_112   2018/03/02
ax21:3 Here comes the second row   id_115   2018/03/02
bC230:13 Here comes the third row  id_234   2018/03/02
```

The data types are

```
print(df.dtypes)

Description             object
ID                      object
Date                    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I want to delete those words which contain a a colon. In this case, this would be wa119:d, ax21:3 and bC230:13 so that my new data set should look like as follows:

```
Description                ID      Date
Here comes the first row   id_112  2018/03/02
Here comes the second row  id_115  2018/03/02
Here comes the third row   id_234  2018/03/02
```

What I tried is the following but none of them worked:

```
re.sub('^\\w+:\\w+', '', df["Description"].astype(str))
re.sub('^\\w+:\\w+', '', df["Description"].astype("str"))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fff/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py", line 17, in <module>
    re.sub('^\\w+:\\w+', '', df["Description"].astype("str"))
  File "C:\Users\fff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `df["Description"].astype("str")` returns a Pandas object (most likely a Series) of strings, not a string itself - the regex works only on a string, not a collection of strings. You're probably looking for something like: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: You should use [`Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Comment: @jrd1: Many thanks for the explanation. I'm new to Python and just learning it.

Comment: @pault: Thanks pault. That was I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
df['Description'] = df["Description"].str.replace(r'^\w+:\w+', '')


>>> df
                  Description      ID        Date
0    Here comes the first row  id_112  2018/03/02
1   Here comes the second row  id_115  2018/03/02
2    Here comes the third row  id_234  2018/03/02
```